# Where is AWS Route 53 hosted zone A record ipv4 address located?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, a-records

I'm trying to find out how to bind A record created in AWS Route 53 hosted zone and my custom domain artem-dev.link bought not on AWS. Here is my A record directs to Cloudfront distribution:

[image]

And this is how my domain provider host records settings section look like:

[image]

So, I need an ipv4 address for adding A record, but I can't find it on AWS.

Comment: You need a CNAME in that case or delegate the entire dns handling to route53 by entering its name servers on your provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Route53 hosted zone and records do not affect your `artem-dev.link` domain because you haven't transferred the DNS management from Namecheap to AWS Route 53.

You have two options here:

1. [Transfer DNS management to AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-inactive.html) and then you won't need to add records in Namecheap, all DNS records will be in Route53 and you already have that settled;
2. Delete the Route53 hosted zone and use Namecheap to manage DNS. [Create ANAME record](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10128/2237/how-to-create-an-alias-record/) (alias CNAME for root domains) in Namecheap: `artem-dev.link -> xxx.cloudfront.net`.

Answer (score 1):

An A-type record only allows to route to IPv4.  If you want to route to a canonic name (like artem-dev.example.com), you need to create a CNAME record.  (Also see comment from @luk2302.)  In the case of the CloudFront distribution, the record is actually an alias, which is an AWS native type of record, not an A record in it usual sense.